# DCD instruction and IRQ stack

Tags: assembly, stack, arm, irq

I'm studying the topic of setting up a stack for different modes of an ARM processor (IRQ, Supervisor, User, ...).
Since setting up different stacks requires the same sequence of instructions (basically only stack address change) I will ask my question resorting to the problem of setting up the IRQ stack.
Provided that I have the following defines:

```
IRQ_Stack EQU 0x8000
NoInt     EQU 0xC0
IRQ32md   EQU 0x12
```

The following code is used to setup the stack (I add line numbers to enable comments):

```
1. MOV r2, #NoInt|IRQ32md
2. MSR CPSR_c, r2
3. LDR r13_irq, =IRQ_NewStack
4. ...
5. ...
6. IRQ_NewStack:
7. DCD IRQ_Stack
```

Line **1** just loads `r2` for the purpose of disabling interrupts and entering IRQ mode
in line **2**, by loading the value into `CPSR_c`.
Then, on line **3**, `LDR` is used to load the (32 bit) address of the `IRQ_NewStack` label into the stack pointer banked in IRQ mode.

Could you please explain me what's the purpose of instruction on line **7**?

I read on the ARM manual that `DCD` is used to *"reserve a 32 bit word"*. When I read *"reserve a 32 bit word"*, I think it's like reserving space for a single 32 bit variable, which means `DCD` acts as `EQU` (may be `EQU` is just a macro for `DCD`...).
But, if this is the case, why should I reserve just a 32 bit word for the whole stack which can grow bigger than just one 32 bit word?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you have a bug in your code. It should be either `LDR r13_irq, =IRQ_Stack`, or `LDR r13_irq, IRQ_NewStack`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DCD reserves 1 32-bit word which points to the stack, it is not the stack itself.